# AWS bucket that is duplicate of another bucket in S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have the following requirement. I'm however unsure of how to go about it

1. Bucket 1 contains data.
2. Bucket 2 should have duplicate data of Bucket 1. Whenever any file is changed in bucket 1, it is also be changed in bucket 2.
3. Data in bucket 2 can be independently changed. However, this data change should **not** be reflected in bucket 1.
4. This entire process must be automated and run in real time.

Comment: The viability of this depends in part on your definition of "real time."  What does that mean, specifically?

Comment: It means that any change in bucket 1 instantly triggers the duplication of data in bucket 2, in contrast to a check every 10 min or so to check for changes. Essentially an event driven model vs polling.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That's an important distinction, "instantly triggers the duplication" (possible) vs. "immediate consistency" (not possible).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you might find [Cross Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-how-setup.html) works for you. This would require the buckets to be in separate regions. It also wouldn't copy items that were replicated from another bucket.

Essentially you just create two buckets in separate regions, create an IAM role allowing the replication, then create a Replication Configuration.

If you already have data in the source bucket that you want to appear in the target bucket, then you will also need to run a sync (you can do this as a one-off via the cli).

Another option is [using AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/content-replication-using-aws-lambda-and-amazon-s3/), which allows the buckets to be in the same region, and gives you more control should you need it. You can also replicate to multiple buckets if you want to.